# Best way of storing differences between 2 images

Tags: image, motion-detection

I am doing motion detection.

I compare 2 images at a time.

The differences are compared at the pixel level.

I want to store the differences in a file.

I have tried saving the hex value into 2 dimensional string and using the binary formatter serializing it out to a file. But the size is 495kb and the original image size is only 32kb.

What is the most efficient way of storing differences?

I am using C#

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Maybe took a look how [bdiff](http://bdiff.sourceforge.net/) is doing it. In general, compare the binary value, not a hex representation. Maybe also the binary formatter serialization adds some overhead.

Comment: Hi, I am already comparing the images at byte level using Emgu/OpenCV.  What I am after is how to store those differences.  Even if I do not convert the bytes to a hex number the size is still 3 times bigger than the original image.  I need to only store the changes but I have to also store the x,y coordinate of that change which is why I was using a 2 dimensional array. Thanks for taking the time to reply.